# Bulk rename files - remove space

Tags: rename

I have hundreds of files in a folder named `transactions 1.csv`,
`transactions 2.csv`, `transactions 3.csv` etc.

How do I remove the space in the file names, so they become `transactions1.csv`, `transactions2.csv`, `transactions3.csv` etc?

Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `bash` (and probably others) you can use `${f// /}` to remove all spaces from `$f`:

```
for f in *.csv; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f// /}"
done
```

Also have a look at the `rename` tool from util-linux:

```
rename ' ' '' *
```

but this only removes the first space, so it has to be applied several times.

There's also another, Perl-based `rename` utility that takes a Perl expression, and can remove all spaces:

```
rename "s/ //g" *
```

(Having two incompatible tools with the same name is confusing.)

Comment: @Thomas Erker - What web resource/book you recommend on learning about bash programming?

Comment: @anonranger Sorry, can't really recommend anything. The *Bash* and *sed & awk* books from oreilly.com might be useful, but I haven't looked in them.

Comment: `rename` can remove all the spaces: `rename "s/ //g" *` or `"s/ /_/g"` etc.